# Definition of 'session' in AppsFlyer

Tags: appsflyer

Precisely, how is a session defined in AppsFlyer data? If a user opens the app and leaves it open for the entire day, using their device to perform other tasks, does this count as only one session for that day even if they return to the app (which remained open but in the background) after a long period of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

- The session starts when user opens application
- The session ends when application goes to background

The minimal session duration is 5 seconds